# Creating .JSON file with the data received from vars_prompt or survey in Ansible

Tags: json, ansible

I have a requirement as below.
I have to get the data from the user in the form of vars_prompt in ansible playbook or survey in AWX and I have to use the data to create .JSON file.

A sample requirement is shown below

I have to use the data obtained from the vars_prompt mentioned below

```
---
- name: Playbook for creating a .JSON file
  hosts: all
  vars_prompt: 
  - name: fruitName
    prompt: Please enter Fruit Name
    default: "Apple"
    private: no
  - name: fruitSize
    prompt: Please enter required fruit size
    default: "Large"
    private: no
  - name: fruitColour
    prompt: Please provide fruit colour
    default: "Red"
    private: no
```

to create a .JSON file as shown below.

```
{
    "fruitName": "Apple",
    "fruitSize": "Large",
    "fruitColour": "Red"
}
```

I am unable to find the correct way of doing it.

Can someone help me on how do it ?
(Even a basic idea which helps in implementing it is highly appreciated)

Answer (score 0):

For example, use [*copy*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/copy_module.html)

```yaml
    - copy:
        dest: fruit.json
        content: |
          {
            "fruitName": "{{ fruitName }}',
            "fruitSize": "{{ fruitSize }}",
            "fruitColour": "{{ fruitColour }}"
          }
```

See also [*template*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/template_module.html#ansible-builtin-template-module-template-a-file-out-to-a-target-host).

Comment: when I tried this (with copy module) and got the values using AWX survey, each line break is folded to a space though I used "|". Is thera any fix for this ?

Comment: Make sure the indentation is precise. If you have a problem [edit] the question and provide [mre].